# Python regex that repeats \d number of times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, repeat, regex-group

Using python regex, I am trying to match as many number of `p` as the the digit first matched in pattern.

**Sample Input**

```
1pp
2p
3ppp
4ppppppppp
```

**Expected Output**

```
1p
None
3ppp
4pppp
```

***Code Tried***
I have tried the following code, where i use named group, and give the name 'dig' to the matched digit, now I want to use `dig` in repetition `{m}`. But the following code does not find any match in `pattern`.

```
pattern = "2pppp"
reTriple = '((?P<dig>\d)p{(?P=dig)})'
regex = re.compile(reTriple,re.IGNORECASE)
matches = re.finditer(regex,pattern)
```

I think the problem is that repetition `{m}` expects an int `m`, where as `dig` is a string. But I can't find a way to concatenate an int to string while keeping it int! I tried casting as follows:

```
reTrip = '((?P<dig>\d)p{%d}'%int('(?P=dig)')+')'
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(?P=dig)'
```

I feel stuck. Can someone please guide.

And its weird that if i instead break reTriple as follows: save the matched digit in a variable first and then concatenate this variable in reTriple, it works, and the expected output is achieved. But this is a work around, and I am looking for a better method.

```
reTriple = '(?P<dig>\d)'
dig = re.search(reTriple , pattern).group('dig')
reTriple = reTriple + '(p{1,' + dig + '})'
```

Comment: did you need only with regex or another way can be fine? , and why the second is None? the input is checked line by line or it's one single string?

Comment: Maybe you could use standard string functions to get the digit and then use it in the regex? Or use string functions for everything.

Comment: @BenyGj I guess the second output is `None` because **2p** is looking for two occurrences of **p** and only finds one on that line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are trying basically comes down to: `(\d+)p{\1}` where you would use capture group 1 as input for how often you need to match "p". However capture group one seems to be returned as text (not numeric) causing you to find no results. Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/YrfRx5/1) for example.

Maybe it helps to split this into two operations. For example:

```
import re

def val_txt(txt):
    i = int(re.search(r'\d+', txt).group(0))
    fnd = re.compile(fr'(?i)\d+p{{{i}}}')
    if fnd.search(txt):
        return fnd.search(txt).group(0)

print(val_txt('2p'))
```

Comment: This is good solution which works for all cases. Considering the input cases from OP, I thought this can be done with just string operations. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can also do pure string operations without depending on any module for the mentioned strings in the question (digits < 10):

```
def val_txt(txt):
    dig = int(txt[0])
    rest_val = 'p' * dig
    return f'{dig}{rest_val}' if txt[1:1+dig] == rest_val else None

print(val_txt('1ppp'))
# 1p
```

Comment: What about something like: `print(val_txt('10pppppppppppppppppppp'))`. Good solution for strings with digits < 10.

Comment: Another small note (I really don't want to be picky) is that OP used `re.IGNORECASE`, meaning there *could* be values like `4PppPp`......potentially. Who knows, maybe OP doesn't need it and you are good to go =)

Comment: @JvdV, Potentially yes. I suggest to OP to use `txt = txt.lower()` at the beginning of the method in that case, though the output is lowercased.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do another approach  something  like this `without regex`:

```
from typing import Union
def  test(txt: str, var: str ='p') -> Union[str, None]: 
    var_count = txt.count(var)
    number = int(txt[0:len(txt) - var_count:]) 
    if number <= var_count: 
        return f'{number}{number * var}' 

    return None
```

lets test it
output:

```
t = ['1pp', '2p', '3ppp', '4ppppppppp', '10pppppppppp']             

for i in t: 
    print(test(i)) 

1p
None
3ppp
4pppp
10pppppppppp
```

Comment: Liked your approach, but using `count` on string is bit inefficient. I suggest @JvdV's method for digits >= 10 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single step regex solution which uses a lambda function to check if there are sufficient `p`'s to match the digits at the beginning of the string; if there are it returns the appropriate string (e.g. `1p` or `3ppp`), otherwise it returns an empty string:

```
import re

strs = ['1pp',
        '2p',
        '3ppp',
        '4ppppppppp'
        ]

for s in strs:
    print(re.sub(r'^(\d+)(p+).*', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2)[:int(m.group(1))] if len(m.group(2)) >= int(m.group(1)) else '', s))
```

Output:

```
1p

3ppp
4pppp
```